# Override forced tag search?

Tags: feature-request, tags, search

As described in [this SO blog entry](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/stack-overflow-search-now-61-less-crappy/), if you type a keyword such as "`subjective`" into the search box in SO, it is automatically coerced to the equivalent tag search "`[subjective]`"

Is there any way to override this?

I would like to be able to search for a keyword within a question, when that keyword happens to be a popular tag, but the question will not necessarily have that tag applied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add quotes around the word:

> "subjective"

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22subjective%22

Comment: Thanks, That works.  Maybe it could be mentioned in the "search options" page?

Comment: This is a great tip, and one that might help to resolve a fwe other recent questions that are related. I wonder if the "Tagged Questions" page could add a little note (with a link) to this effect if it's viewed as the result of a search remapping. That would make this useful feature a lot more visible.

Answer (score 0):

Use Google to conduct your search: `site:stackoverflow.com subjective`

Comment: There are some disadvantages to that.  On google, a keyword is a keyword, and no extra weighting is given to question titles.  Also comments are indexed which gives some false positives.  And you can't use some of the other criteria such as accepted answers only or minimum vote count.